# replace img src value

Tags: php, html, regex

I am having data in this format:

```
<img src="cid:ii_jhzwfy6l0_163c993284ad67a3" width="295" height="65">
<img src="cid:ii_jhzwfy6l0_163c99368434384384a3" width="295" height="65">
this is text with some images
```

this is just an string.

I want to replace src value of above string with actual values which is store in array like:

```
[attachments] => Array
        (
            [0] => logo.png
            [1] => sample.png
        )
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: SO What have you tried? Show some more code if only to add some context to the question please

Comment: so what you have tried so far?

Comment: *How can i do that ?*, by programming it! Please show us what you've tried already. SO is a specific problem solving site, not a place you go to to receive code for free.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have tried using new DOMDocument; but wont work for me

Comment: Currently we have no idea where the `<img.....>` strings are held. Are you trying to replace in line HTML or data in a file or what? Some more code would help us to help you

Comment: It depends how the attachments-array and the img-tags are related. but i guess you will need to use a regular-expression looking for `cid:` in `src` and then replace it.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback` with the regex `<img src="(cid:ii_[^"]+)"`

Answer (score 0):

Match src using regx - src\s*=\s*"(.+?)" from img tab.
Replace the value array by array[0] and [1]
---- Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = '<img src="cid:ii_jhzwfy6l0_xxx63c99676ghf4ad67a3" width="295" height="65">
<img src="cid:ii_jhzwfy6l0_163c993284ad67a3" width="295" height="65"><img src="cid:ii_jhzwfy6l0_163c99368434384384a3" width="295" height="65">';

$arr = [
    'logo.png', 
    'sample.png', 
    'one.png'
];

echo preg_replace_callback('/cid:ii_[^"]+/', function($matches) use (&$arr) {
    return array_shift($arr);
}, $string);
```

Comment: This only works exactly for the given example. What if there are multiple images on the same line or lines without images?